OS memory management with paging
I have a task where I don't understand the memory management of 2 processes by an OS using paging. As scheduling method I used "round robin" since they both perform I/O. There are 2 assumptions that need to be taken care of:

they fit separately, but not together in memory
they both use a shared piece of data, namely a certificate that the computer offers to provide authentication to the online platforms

Is with the first assumption intended that the pages of both processes are in physical memory but some pages in swap space because the physical memory is full? If so, is it necessary to explain cache management with LRU or do I just show what the swap space looks like? Or is intended that only the pages of one process can be in the physical memory and all the pages of the second process on swap space?
Regarding the second assumption, do I put the certificate fixed in the physical memory without doing anything, or do I need to put the certificate as a page in each address space (but then there are 2 certificates page frames in the physical memory?) and then let it stay in physical memory by using LRU?

Are you trying to implement your own OS, or are you asking about the behavior of an existing OS?  If it's the latter, which OS are you asking about?
